# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 14 path $ with Object and SQLite

Tags: java, android, json, notifications, gson

I am trying to store an Android Notification Object in a SQLite database and I am getting an  error.

First, before I explain the error, let me expalin what does work. I have a NotificationListenerService class that listens for notifications and blocks them from showing up. You can see this in the class below. When the notifications are blocked, I want to store them in a SQLite DB. However, my issue was how to store the Notification object in the database so I went the GSON to JSON route. So whenever a notification is destroyed, it converts the Notification object to Json and stores it in the database (along with a few other things).

**NotificationListenerService:**

```
public class NotificationListenerServiceUsage extends NotificationListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationListenerSer";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
        cancelAllNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){
        // 1. Getting DB Context and initializing SQLiteDatabase
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = context.openOrCreateDatabase("notifications", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

        // 2. Initialize the DBHelper class.
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(sqLiteDatabase);

        // 3. Getting the content for the DB
        String notificationKey = sbn.getKey();
        Integer notificationID = sbn.getId();
        long postTime = sbn.getPostTime();
        Notification notificationContent = sbn.getNotification();

        // 3.1 Converting the Notification Object into a String
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String notificationInput = gson.toJson(notificationContent);


        // 4. Saving into the DB
        dbHelper.saveNotifications(notificationKey, notificationID, postTime, notificationInput);

        // FOR TESTING PURPOSES
        Notification finalNotificationObj = gson.fromJson(notificationInput, Notification.class);

        // FOR TESTING PURPOSES
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved: " + "INPUT: " + notificationContent);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved: " + "JSON: " + notificationInput);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved: " + "OUTPUT: " + finalNotificationObj );
    }

}
```

And the resulted Json that gets rendered is below:

```
{
   "audioAttributes":{
      "mContentType":4,
      "mFlags":2048,
      "mFormattedTags":"",
      "mSource":-1,
      "mUsage":5
   },
   "audioStreamType":-1,
   "color":0,
   "defaults":0,
   "extras":{
      "mParcelledData":{
         "mNativePtr":3569564416
      }
   },
   "flags":0,
   "icon":2131230820,
   "iconLevel":0,
   "ledARGB":0,
   "ledOffMS":0,
   "ledOnMS":0,
   "mChannelId":"channel1",
   "mSmallIcon":{
      "mString1":"com.example.finalproject",
      "mType":2
   },
   "number":0,
   "priority":1,
   "visibility":0,
   "when":1587406911152
}
```

**So what's the problem?**

I am able to successfully store the string Json in the Database but when I pull it back out of the database, and try to convert it back to the Notification object, I get an IllegalStateException. The stack trace is below for reference. I have a feeling there is an issue when storing the string Json and pulling it back out because in the above Notificaiton Listener file, I just logged a few things and the conversion to Json and back was successful and matched exactly. Below is the Database helper class that I am using which shows how things are being stored and pulled back out. The error in questions occurs in the readNotifications() method.

Any thoughts as to why this error is occuring?

**Database Access Class:**

```
public class DBHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";

    public DBHelper(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        this.sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteDatabase;
    }

    public void createTable (){
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS notifications" + "(notificationKey TEXT, notificationID INTEGER, postTime BIGINT, notificatoinContent TEXT)");
    }

    public ArrayList<NotificationObject> readNotifications(){
        // 1. Checking the table and creating a NotificationObject instance
        createTable();
        ArrayList<NotificationObject> notificationObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        // 2. Starting the cursor at the top of the notification Table
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(("SELECT * from notifications"), null);

        // 3. Gets the index of all of the columns so that the cursor can reference it from the row
        int keyIndex = c.getColumnIndex("notificationKey");
        int notificationIDIndex = c.getColumnIndex("notificationID");
        int postTimeIndex = c.getColumnIndex("postTime");
        int notificationContentIndex = c.getColumnIndex("postTime");

        // 4. Moves the cursor to the top
        c.moveToFirst();

        // 5. While loop to loop through all the rows
        while (!c.isAfterLast()){

            // 5.1 Getting all of the values from row of the cursor
            String notificationKey = c.getString(keyIndex);
            Integer notificationID = c.getInt(notificationIDIndex);
            long postTime = c.getLong(postTimeIndex);
            String notificationContent = c.getString(notificationContentIndex);

            // 5.2 Converting Notification content back to Notification Object
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Notification finalNotificationObj = gson.fromJson(notificationContent, Notification.class);

            // 5.3 Adds all of the content to the NotificationObject Object
            NotificationObject notificationObject = new NotificationObject(notificationKey, notificationID, postTime, finalNotificationObj);

            // 5.4 Adds the notificationObject to the arraylist
            notificationObjects.add(notificationObject);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return notificationObjects;
    }

    public void saveNotifications (String notificationKey, Integer notificationID, long postTime, String notificationContent){

        createTable();
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO notifications (notificationKey, notificationID, postTime, notificatoinContent)" +
                " VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", notificationKey, notificationID, postTime, notificationContent));
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
2020-04-20 13:55:52.881 12060-12060/com.example.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.finalproject, PID: 12060
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 14 path $
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
        at com.example.finalproject.BatchNotifications.DBHelper.readNotifications(DBHelper.java:54)
        at com.example.finalproject.BatchNotifications.Batch_Notifications.getHeldNotifications(Batch_Notifications.java:290)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 14 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:386)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817) 
        at com.example.finalproject.BatchNotifications.DBHelper.readNotifications(DBHelper.java:54) 
        at com.example.finalproject.BatchNotifications.Batch_Notifications.getHeldNotifications(Batch_Notifications.java:290) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Don't serialize objects that are not under your control. `Notification` comes from Android SDK. Its internal structure, which you're trying to capture, may change between system versions (your app will crash after system update), may be different across manufacturers (your app will crash when I get a new phone and migrate my apps) and who knows what else. Make a custom [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) storing the minimal subset of information for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Consider using [an alternative to Gson](https://github.com/square/moshi) which automatically prohibits you from serializing anything from Android SDK (or `java.*` or `kotlin.*` package) forcing better habits on yourself.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Absolutly - creating a custom DTO is the end goal and would be what is used in production (and is currently in development). We are currently just tring to get a proof of concept working and wanted to make sure something like this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the Database helper class posted above. In Step 3 of the readNotifications method, the line

```
int notificationContentIndex = c.getColumnIndex("postTime");
```

was pointed to the incorrect column. It was pointing to the postTime column which was returning an int value instead of a JSON string. Passing that int to the GSON / JSON converter resulted in the above error. Pointing it to the correct column resolved the issue.